# Can I create a Maven POM-only (BOM) build using the Gradle maven plugin to be deployed to Nexus?

Tags: maven, gradle, nexus, spring-boot-gradle-plugin, maven-bom

I have a Gradle project which uses [Spring's dependency management plugin](https://github.com/spring-gradle-plugins/dependency-management-plugin) to define a list of dependency versions.  I am also using the [Maven plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/maven_plugin.html) to deploy the project to a Maven repository.

I would like to be able to deploy this as a Maven bill of materials (BOM) so that I can use it in other Gradle projects to define my dependency versions.  I have been able to get this to work so long as I also deploy a JAR file.  However, the JAR is completely empty and superfluous.  My goal is to generate and deploy just the POM file, like I would be able to do if this were a Maven project with a "pom" packaging.

If I manually exclude the JAR from the list of artifacts to be published, then nothing gets installed, not even the POM file.

This is a test build to demonstrate the issue:

```
group 'test'
version '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'

buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()

  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.5.1.RELEASE' //Matches the Spring IO version
  }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'maven'

dependencyManagement {
  dependencies {
    dependency 'cglib:cglib-nodep:3.2.4'
    dependency 'junit:junit:4.12'
  }
}

////Uncommenting this causes nothing at all to be deployed:
//jar.enabled = false
//configurations.archives.artifacts.with { archives ->
//  archives.removeAll { it.type == 'jar' }
//}
```

The above correctly produces and installs the following POM file into my local Maven repo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>test</groupId>
  <artifactId>gradle-pom-packaging-test</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

However, it also installs a JAR file that is empty save for the MANIFEST.MF file.

I was able to successfully get this working using the `maven-publish` plugin.  However, I'm also making use of the [Gradle Sonatype Nexus plugin](https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-nexus-plugin) to publish the artifact to a Nexus instance.  As this builds upon the `maven` plugin, the `maven-publish` plugin will not work for my needs.  The following is all I needed to add to get it working with the `maven-publish` plugin:

```
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
publishing {
  publications {
    maven(MavenPublication) {
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a way to generate and deploy just the POM file using the `maven` Gradle plugin, like I would be able to do if this were a Maven project with a "pom" packaging?

Answer (score 11):

In Gradle 6+ versions, we can use [Gradle Java Platform Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_platform_plugin.html) to publish a maven-bom without many configurations and scripting.

```
group 'test.platform.simple.bom'
version '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    maven {
        mavenCentral()
    }        
}

apply plugin: 'java-platform'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

javaPlatform {
    allowDependencies()
}

dependencies {
    constraints {
        api 'junit:junit:4.12'
        api 'cglib:cglib-nodep:3.2.4'
        // runtime 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.5' <-- runtime constraint
        // api project(":core") <-- constraint from local project
    }

    // api platform('com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-bom:2.9.8') <-- constraint from another platform
}

publishing {
  publications {
    maven(MavenPublication) {
      from components.javaPlatform
    }
  }
}
```

Dependencies to be managed can be defined under dependencies as [api or runtime constraints](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_platform_plugin.html#sec:java_platform_separation). **Constraints** can be utilized to manage dependencies [from a local project](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_platform_plugin.html#sec:java_platform_project_constraints) as well as [from another platform/bom](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_platform_plugin.html#sec:java_platform_bom_import). Please note that we need to configure a Maven publication that uses the [javaPlatform](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_platform_plugin.html#sec:java_platform_publishing) component to get it published as a maven bom artifact.

Comment: How does this work in combination with "apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'"? As far as i know spring dependency managment does not work with java-platform

Answer (score 5):

Tha [acdcjunior](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1850609/acdcjunior)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56302270/7873775) can be improved a little.
Dependencies in the `build.gradle` can by declared in the standard `dependencies` section. Also, in `pom.xml` of a BOM versions should be declared in `dependencyManagement` section:

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
    id 'maven-publish'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '1.0.0'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    api 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.9'
    api 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.11'
}

publishing {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url = "$nexusUrl"
            credentials {
                username = "$nexusUsername"
                password = "$nexusPassword"
            }
        }
    }

    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            groupId = "${project.group}"
            artifactId = "${project.name}"
            version = "${project.version}"

            pom.withXml {
                asNode().children().last() + {
                    resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST

                    name 'My BOM'
                    description 'My Bill of Materials (BOM)'

                    dependencyManagement {
                        dependencies {
                            project.configurations.each { conf ->
                                conf.dependencies.each { dep ->
                                    dependency {
                                        groupId "${dep.group}"
                                        artifactId "${dep.name}"
                                        version "${dep.version}"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The resulting `pom.xml` can be published to Nexus with the command

```
./gradlew clean build publish -i
```

or to a local Maven repo (`~/.m2/repository`)

```
./gradlew clean build pTML -i
```

This notation is not only shorter but also allows processing dependencies. For example, perform vulnerabilities scanning using OWASP Dependency-Check plugin:

```
plugins {
    //...
    id 'org.owasp.dependencycheck' version '5.3.0'
}

dependencyCheck {
    failBuildOnCVSS = 9 //Critical Severity
}

check.dependsOn dependencyCheckAnalyze
```

Answer (score 2):

You could have a `build.gradle` such as:

```groovy
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: 'signing'

publishing {
    repositories {
        maven {
            def releasesRepoUrl = "https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/"
            def snapshotsRepoUrl = "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
            url = version.endsWith('SNAPSHOT') ? snapshotsRepoUrl : releasesRepoUrl
            credentials {
                username ossrhUsername
                password ossrhPassword
            }
        }
    }

    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            groupId = 'com.example.id'
            artifactId = 'my-artifact-id'
            version = '1.0.0'

            pom.withXml {
                asNode().children().last() + {
                    resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST

                    name 'My Lib Name'
                    description 'My Lib Description'
                    url 'https://example.com/id/lib'

                    licenses {
                        license {
                            name 'The Apache License, Version 2.0'
                            url 'http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt'
                        }
                    }
                    scm {
                        connection 'scm:git:git@example.com:acdcjunior/lib/id.git'
                        developerConnection 'scm:git:git@example.com:acdcjunior/lib/id.git'
                        url 'git@example.lib/id.git'
                    }
                    developers {
                        developer {
                            id 'someone'
                            name 'Someone Name'
                            email 'someone@example.com'
                        }
                    }
                    dependencies {
                        dependency {
                            groupId 'com.example.other'
                            artifactId 'some-dependency'
                            version '1.0.0'
                        }
                        dependency {
                            groupId 'org.apache.commons'
                            artifactId 'commons-lang3'
                            version '3.9'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

signing {
    sign publishing.publications.maven
}
```

Example of a project using this: https://github.com/acdcjunior/domain-id/blob/master/domain-id-all/build.gradle

Comment: Thanks! It worked for my case. It would be helpful if you could remove the other stuff about signing as it not in the OP's question

Answer (score 1):

You should consider that plugin which has a DSL to create BOMs the  gradle way :

https://github.com/xvik/gradle-pom-plugin

Julien

Comment: More generally, this is an enhancement to the standard maven-publish plugin (an enhancement which I don't really need since I need the Spring dependency management plugin to generate the dependencyManagement section of the POM, and that also does the additional optional/provided stuff the gradle-pom-plugin does).  I did get this to work with the maven-publish plugin by adding `publishing {
  publications {
    maven(MavenPublication) {
    }
  }
}`

Comment: One thing that I didn't mention in the opening question is that I'm also using the [Gradle Sonatype Nexus plugin](https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-nexus-plugin) to publish the artifacts to my nexus repository (primarily for the repositoryUrl/snapshotRepositoryUrl functionality).  That makes use of the `maven` plugin functionality, so using `maven-publish` or `ru.vyarus.pom` would not work well, as it uses a different mechanism to configure and upload the artifact.  I'll update my question accordingly.