# Updating build dependencies in lots of microservices easily

Tags: java, spring-boot, architecture, microservices, software-design

Using shared libraries in microservices is a bad practice. But every microservice depends on frameworks and libraries: Spring Boot, Kafka Java Client etc.

**If a system consists of 30 microservices based on Spring Boot and using Gradle or Maven as a build tool and distributed as Docker images, is there an easy way to update Spring Boot version in all microservices? Updating all microservices one by one takes a lot of efforts. And the more microservices a system has, the more efforts is required.**

And the reason for an update may be a security vulnerability in some of dependencies.
For example, [Spring Boot 2.2.0.RELEASE](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/2.2.0.RELEASE) depends on Tomcat 9.0.27 that has vulnerability [CVE-2020-1938](http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2020-1938) (just as an example). The vulnerability was fixed in Tomcat 9.0.31, so updating to [Spring Boot 2.2.4.RELEASE](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/2.2.4.RELEASE) will solve the issue.

A workaround is to declare Spring Boot version in `build.gradle` as `2.2.+`. But someone still has to rebuild all microservices (e.g., on Jenkins).

Also, with this approach you loose control over version management and delegate it to Gradle (always use the latest one version possible). To still have the control over dependencies, versions can be declared in the `gradle.properties` and mounted into workspace somehow by Jenkins:

```
spring.version=2.2.4.RELEASE
```

If the vulnerability is critical there is no time to wait for new Spring Boot version with a fix and Tomcat has to be updated explicitly in the `build.gradle`. Or even replaced with Undertow what also requires changes in the `build.gradle`.

Using standalone Tomcat instead of embedded also doesn't help much because microservices are distributed as Docker images and not as WAR files deployed to a servlet container.

In Java EE security updates *in theory* was super easy. You update an application server (e.g. WildFly) or apply a security patch and if application uses only Java EE API, no further action is required. Is there a similar concept of easy dependencies updates for microservies (at least in theory)?

Comment: While not canonical, that is a very interesting question.

Comment: This is the reason many companies moved to monorepo.

Comment: There should be a team for each microservice... so just notify each team that they should update their dependency?  They only have to update one service each so that can be done quickly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a side note, microservices bring value by making components more autonomous and maintainable but that has also a cost : integrate them and maintain them is not cheap. So the microservices granularity should also be considered under that aspect too.

> If a system consists of 30 microservices based on Spring Boot and
>   using Gradle or Maven as a build tool and distributed as Docker
>   images, is there an easy way to update Spring Boot version in all
>   microservices? Updating all microservices one by one takes a lot of
>   efforts. And the more microservices a system has, the more efforts is
>   required.

With CI tools as Jenkins you quote, relevant automated tests in each microservice application, that is not so hard to update the spring version of their pom/gradle file and even to deploy them in an integration environment with automation IT infrastructure tools as Ansible.
In a general way, updating the dependency version of all projects may be done with maven/gradle plugin if the projects belong to a multi module project (maven version plugin and gradle version plugin do that).
If projects don't belong to a multi module project there is also alternative but you should add manual SCM retrievals step.
The whole task may be done with a shell script or still better with a jenkins job taking [as custom job parameter](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Define+Parameters) the spring boot version to use and that you can execute on demand. With Jenkins that is still nicer because you can write a pipeline job that integrates both SCM retrieval, docker agent, build execution and also shell execution when needed. And overall you keep all details of executed steps (success as failure) in a tool that your team use.

> In Java EE security updates in theory was super easy. You update an
>   application server (e.g. WildFly) or apply a security patch and if
>   application uses only Java EE API, no further action is required

From my very recent memories, updating Java EE servers on all environments was never an easy task (not as simple as updating a version in a file).
Official procedures to update Weblogic and Websphere are very very picky, the updates also take much time because these servers are how to say... bloat, and the rollback to the previous version is not always easy either.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to [davidxxx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/270371/davidxxx)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60469902/7873775) I came up with the solution I consider clean and easy.

The general idea is to simply automate manual the process of updating libraries versions instead of using a workaround (e.g. dynamic versions `1.+` making builds non-deterministic, mounting centrally managed `gradle.properties` on Jenkins etc.).

1. Use BOM (bill of materials) that is a special kind of POM that bundles multiple dependencies and supplies their versions.

   ```
   dependencies {
       implementation platform("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:${springBootVersion}")
       implementation platform("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}")

       implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web' //version is taken from BOM
       implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-context' //version is taken from BOM
       //...
   }
   ```
2. Create a custom BOM with your specific dependencies as described in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60798021/7873775)

   ```
   dependencies {
       //...
       implementation platform("com.example:my-dependencies:${myBomVersion}")
       //...
   }
   ```
3. This way in a `build.gradle` only BOM dependencies will be declared with versions. All other dependencies will use versions supplied by BOMs. Declare BOM versions in `gradle.properties`

   ```
   springBootVersion=2.2.4.RELEASE
   springCloudVersion=Hoxton.SR1
   myBomVersion=1.0.0
   ```
4. To update dependencies you only need to update BOM version in the `gradle.properties`. This task can be automated using `sed`

   ```
   sed -i'.original' -E 's|(springBootVersion)=(.+)|\1=2.2.6.RELEASE|g' gradle.properties
   ```
5. A Bash script to update versions can be created, e.g. `./update-version.sh springBootVersion 2.2.6.RELEASE` and called in a parametrised Jenkins job. Repository, version variable name and new version value can be supplied as parameters.

The described approach slightly simplifies the process of updating libraries while having deterministic builds (you always know what versions of libraries are used).